# Elasticsearch error Magento 2.4 reindex Catalog Search index

Tags: elasticsearch-7, magento2.4

Suddenly, I think we made no changes, we have an error reindexing Catalog Search:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"mapper [category_position_25536] cannot be changed from type [text] to [integer]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"mapper [category_position_25536] cannot be changed from type [text] to [integer]"},"status":400}
```

I reindexed a couple of times, used bin/magento index:reset, removed the indexes like this:
curl -XDELETE https://host:9200/prefix_product_4_v904 (this for all indexes)

For now there is no error doing a search, there is just no results. Even on categorypages there are no products showing up.

Can someone point me in the right direction?